# How to draw a linear axis with different labels and references

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, draw, axis, ticks

In line with my previous question [How to draw a linear axis with tick labels at different alternative distances?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562834/how-to-draw-a-linear-axis-with-tick-labels-at-different-alternative-distances), which was answered successfully by @user30471, now I need to make a variation based on those graphs and his or her answer, but I don't know how to modify the code to achieve it.
I leave pictures of what I need to do now. Thank you very much!

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is what I have tried so far

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
   \draw[SteelBlue,thick,-LaTeX](1,0)-- ++(12,0) node[right] [right=0.5cm, below]{$t$};
   \foreach \lab  [count=\c] in {\frac{1}{(1+i)^n},\frac{1}{(1+i)^{n-1}},X,\frac{1}{(1+i)^{p+1}},\frac{1}{(1+i)^p},\frac{1}{(1+i)^{p-1}},X,\frac{1}{(1+i)^3},\frac{1}{(1+i)^2},\frac{1}{(1+i)},X} {
      \if\lab X\relax% jump over gap
         \node at (\c,0)[SteelBlue,thick]{//};
      \else
        \draw[SteelBlue,thick] (\c,0.2) -- ++(0,-0.4);
        \draw[SteelBlue] (13-\c,0) -- ++(0,\c/2-6)
                  -- ++(\c-12,0)node[left]{$\lab$};
      \fi
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{center}

but I can't understand the logic of the positions of the axis labels and I don't know how to put the labels and the references because the labels are different from the references

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please on problem per question. The second part of your question is unclear. BTE, what you try so far?

Comment: Sorry for the two questions on one topic. Perhaps it is best to separate them since you correspond to different topics.
The second question refers to including a graphical argument in a function, equation, mathematical operator in order to graphically represent what goes in that place, instead of putting "X" for having a graph like a rectangle, square or circle or whatever figure as a reference and that it is more graphic, to later clarify graphically what it represents, it is more attractive and didactic. I edited the post with more details. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will be beter, if limit your question to one problem (which - I hope -- is solved in my answer) and for other ask new question. In it, please show us (in form of small but complete document) what you try so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14159mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb, 
lbl/.style = {text depth=1ex, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\draw[blue,->] (0,0) -- (9,0);
% ticks
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {0 , 1, 2, 3, (p-1), p, (n-1), n}
\draw (1.2*\j,1mm) node[lbl, above] {$\mathsf{C_{\i}}$} 
                   -- ++ (0,-2mm) 
    \ifnum\j>0  node[below] {$\mathsf{\frac{1}{(1+i)^{\i}}}$}\fi;
\draw[double]   (1.2*3.5,1mm) -- ++ (-1mm,-2mm)
                (1.2*5.5,1mm) -- ++ (-1mm,-2mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
or as it can be understand from edited question, for the first part of question you like to have:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, svgnames, margin=3.14159mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb, 
lbl/.style = {text depth=1ex, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\draw[SteelBlue, thick, ->] (0,0) -- (12,0);
\draw[double]   (1.2*3.5,1mm) -- ++ (-1mm,-2mm)
                (1.2*6.5,1mm) -- ++ (-1mm,-2mm);
% ticks
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {0 , 1, 2, 3, (p-1), p, (p+1), (n-1), n}
{
\draw[SteelBlue]    (1.2*\j,1mm) node[lbl, above] {$\mathsf{C_{\i}}$} 
                                -- ++ (0,-2mm) coordinate (t\j);
\ifnum\j>0  
\node (n\j) [left,inner sep=0pt] at (0,-0.6*\j) {$\mathsf{\frac{1}{(1+i)^{\i}}}$};
\draw[densely dashed,SteelBlue] (n\j.4) -| (t\j);
\fi;
}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb,
lbl/.style = {text depth=1ex, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\draw[SteelBlue, thick, ->] (0,0) -- (12,0);
\draw[double]   (1.2*3.5,1mm) -- ++ (-1mm,-2mm)
                (1.2*6.5,1mm) -- ++ (-1mm,-2mm);
% ticks
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {0 , 1, 2, 3, (p-1), p, (p+1), (n-1), n, n+1}
{
\draw[SteelBlue]    (1.2*\j,1mm) node[lbl, above] {$\mathsf{C_{\i}}$}
                                -- ++ (0,-2mm) coordinate (t\j);
}
%
\path[draw=SteelBlue,densely dotted] 
    (t0) -- ++ (0,-2) node[below] {$a(1,n,i)$}
    (t1) -- ++ (0,-1) node[below] {$a(0,n,i)$}
    (t8) -- ++ (0,-2) node[below] {$s(1,n,1)$}
    (t9) -- ++ (0,-1) node[below] {$a(0,n,1)$}
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb,
lbl/.style = {text depth=1ex, inner sep=1pt, align=left}
                        ]
\draw[SteelBlue, thick, ->] (0,0) -- (12,0);
\draw[double]   (1.2*3.5,1mm) -- ++ (-1mm,-2mm)
                (1.2*6.5,1mm) -- ++ (-1mm,-2mm);
% ticks
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {0 , 1, 2, 3, (p-1), p, (p+1), (n-1), n}
{
\draw[SteelBlue]    (1.2*\j,1mm) node[lbl, above] {$\mathsf{C_{\i}}$}
                                -- ++ (0,-2mm) coordinate (t\j);
}
%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={lbl,below=3mm, font=\footnotesize}]
\path
    (t0) node   {$\mathsf{C_{(0)}}$}
    (t1) node   {$\mathsf{I_{(0,1)}}$\\
                                   $\mathsf{C_{(1)}}$}
    (t2) node   {$\mathsf{I_{(1,2)}}$\\
                 $\mathsf{I_{(0,2)}}$\\
                 $\mathsf{C_{(2)}}$}
%
    (t5) node   {$\mathsf{I_{(p-1,p)}}$\\
                 $\mathsf{I_{(0,p)}}$\\
                 $\mathsf{C_{(p)}}$}
%
    (t7) node   {$\mathsf{I_{(n-2,n-1)}}$}
%
    (t8) node   {$\mathsf{I_{(n-1,n)}}$\\
                 $\mathsf{I_{(0,n)}}$\\
                 $\mathsf{C_{(n)}}$}
    ;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! is exactly what I needed to do. Thank you!

Comment: @ArielFernandez, you are welcome!